# Reading return data from php json_encode

Tags: php, html, json, jquery

I'm trying to read the data sent back to my ajax request from the server. I echo back an array then I want to read each value and place it on the desired place on the page. I'm not sure how to work with the JSON that was sent back. The example I looked at seemed to say I just needed to reference it like an array, but that doesn't work.

```
//AJAX Request
$.post("getData.php", {trackingNum: trackNum},
function(result) {
    alert(result);
    usrID(result[0]);
    setTracking(result[1]);
    carType(result[2]);
    status(result[3]);
});

//PHP
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $array[0] = $row[0];
    $array[1] = $row[1];
    $array[2] = $row[2];
    $array[3] = $row[3];
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

What I'm getting back from the alert looks like this:
    ["2","D78A19C","Nissan","Sanding"]
But it won't reference like an array. Help?

Comment: json_encode is going to encode the string as JSON... What does the data actually look like prior to encoding?

Comment: You should use proper keys, not just an array of strings.

Comment: I would recommend to use some meaningful keywords in the array.
For instance: `$array['username'] = $row[..]` and then in your js code you could use it that way: `result.username` (object).
Which is much more semantically correct than `result[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify that return data is type of **JSON**.

use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.post` or just use

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: "getData.php", 
     data: {trackingNum: trackNum},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
         alert(result);
         usrID(result[0]);
         setTracking(result[1]);
         carType(result[2]);
         status(result[3]);
     }
 });
```

**Tip**: get rid of `mysql_*` functions and instead use **mysqli** or **PDO**.

Comment: Unless he wants to make a post, just look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and search for json. Great example